# [PHP][MySQL]How To SELECT data with two constrain?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm new to PHP+MySQL programming

I want to SELCET data using tow constrain at once,

the cons1 is

```
Tid=user02 and Fid=user01
```

and cons2 is

```
Tid=user01 and Fid=user02
```

the data I want to output is something like:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Tid='user02' AND Fid='user01');
```

+

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Tid='user01' AND Fid='user02');
```

= what I want

can it be done in single line?

or can make a result which stored $result1 and $result2

thanks for taking time reading my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `OR` the two conditions resulting in a single query:

```
SELECT * FROM chat 
   WHERE (Tid='user02' AND Fid='user01') 
      OR (Tid='user01' AND Fid='user02')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat WHERE Tid='user02' AND Fid='user01' OR Tid='user01' AND Fid='user02'");
```

Some reading : [boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) and the [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/non-typed-operators.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
 $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat WHERE Tid='user02' AND Fid='user01' 
                        UNION SELECT * FROM chat WHERE Tid='user01' AND Fid='user02'");
```